# Точка зрения: Владимир Плунгян о проблемах преподавания русского языка

Tags: методика

Владимир Плунгян (доктор филологических наук, профессор, член-корреспондент РАН, заместитель директора Института русского языка имени В.В. Виноградова РАН, заведующий кафедрой теоретической и прикладной лингвистики МГУ им. М.В. Ломоносова).

Может быть, попробуем поспорить с В. Плунгяном:

1. **Ситуация со школьным русским без преувеличения катастрофическая. Деградация была многолетней и непрерывной, и сейчас, в эпоху ЕГЭ, она, кажется, достигла максимума.**
   Об этом сложно судить и хочется верить, что не всё так плохо и не всё только деградирует. Возможно, в обществе есть силы, способные хотя бы в будущем изменить ситуацию.
2. **Русская орфография и пунктуация сложны, во многом традиционны, во многом иррациональны — это надо прямо сказать школьникам.**
   Это неверно. Система русского письма логична и сочетает в себе традицию и современное понятие о языке.  Не стоит называть иррациональным то, что  еще просто недостаточно понято и освоено.
3. **Бессмысленные, косноязычные, расплывчатые, противоречивые, устаревшие и просто неверные утверждения встречаются в учебниках русского языка на каждой странице; и в современных учебниках их стало еще больше, чем в старых — те тоже были не сахар, но хотя бы покороче и без таких претензий на «научность».**
   Это верно, псевдонаука у нас явно на высоте. Об этом можно судить хотя бы по тому, как преподается фонетика и фонология.
4. **Чтобы грамотно писать, не нужно отличать сочинение от подчинения и управление от примыкания.** 
   Это крайне ошибочная и вредная точка зрения. Человек не может ясно мыслить или общаться с другими людьми, если он в совершенстве не изучил возможности формы, то есть грамматику языка. (Для сравнения: даже великим музыкантам необходимо знать нотную грамоту.)  Но при изучении грамматики  должна быть тесная связь между теорией и практикой:  школьникам следует изучать классические образцы и учиться составлять собственные оригинальные тексты. Традиционные школьные разборы  слишком формальны  и не имеют связи с практическими задачами.

Comment: А что Вы думаете по этому поводу? Насчет пункта 2, насколько мне известно, вы согласны.

Comment: Считаю, пунктуация действительно сильно усложнена. К орфографии это меньше относится.

Comment: Серж, я принципиально различаю систему русского правописания (меня в ней всё устраивает, я не хотела бы, чтобы грамотно написанный текст выглядел по-другому) и правила, которые описывают  эту систему. Эти правила не объясняют логику нашего письма, это правила-наблюдения, но при этом они очень категоричны и однозначно требовательны.

Comment: Вера, насчет грамотного написанного текста, конечно знания грамматики нужны, и я это оговорил в своем ответе. В моем ответе речь шла исключительно о написания текста под диктовку.

Answer (score 1):

Из всего сказанного, могу выразить сомнение по поводу 2 и 4 пунктов. Действительно, для чего нужно знать управление/подчинение, чтобы грамотно писать? Это два разных уровня: достаточно знать орфографию. Другое дело, если речь будет идти о том, что надо ли знать грамматику,чтобы грамотно мыслить, правильно составлять предложения. Что касается пункта, несмотря на всю логичность орфографии и пунктуации, иррациональность все же есть. По поводу остальных двух пунктов мне сказать просто нечего: я не знаком с русскими учебниками, как и со всей школьной программой. Поэтому говорить что-то трудно.

Comment: Серж, речь идет не о школьных диктовках, а об умении написать текст на любую тему, как вы его напишете без элементарного знания грамматики? И кажущаяся иррациональность письма следует из того, что мы пытаемся внести логику и порядок в практический язык, имеющий многовековую историю развития. Естественно,  приходится учитывать традиции, никак не обойтись без исключений. Но мы сейчас имеем лучшее решение из всех других возможных вариантов. И что еще интересно: по каким учебникам вы изучали   язык и почему вы не можете оценить  состояние грамотности людей, с которыми общаетесь на русском языке?

Comment: Вера, оценить грамотность  людей (особенно с теми ,с которыми я общаюсь),мне не представляет никакого труда. Я имею в виду систему школьного образования в России. Я учился в Армении, учился по учебникам, которые предназначены для армянского сектора. А эти учебники чересчур примитивны.

Answer (score 1):

1. Люди уже никогда не станут другими. Будет меньшинство, которое умеет читать большие тексты и большинство, их читать не умеющее. В силу того, что вторые будут ограничены в словарном запасе преимущество будет у первых.
2. Согласен с Плунгяным. Сочетание всех возможных принципов письма (морфемный, фонетический и исторический) логики в современную орфогрпафию не добавляют.
3. Ну, это следствие первого пункта.
4. Мы знания из книжек узнаём, а истину передают изустно. Граматике и принципам построения предложения школьник учится читая и слушая речь взрослых. Отличать управление от примыкания при этом необязательно. Для сравнения, Римский-Корсаков только будучи профессором Петербургской консерватории обнаружил недостатки в своём музыкальном образовании и сам стал изучать предметы там преподаваемые.

Comment: Хочется верить, что не всё так безнадежно. Вспомним мрачное средневековье, когда отдельные островки знаний существовали и бережно сохранялись этим самым меньшинством, а потом наступила эпоха Возрождения. И вообще, говорят, что предсказания раньше сбывались чаще, так как хорошо была видна колея, по которой движется человечество, а сейчас такая ситуация уже невозможна. Мир так стремительно меняется, что предсказать что-либо трудно.

Answer (score 1):

1. Охотно верю: путающихся в "-тся" и "-ться" становится всё больше. Это сравнительно новое явление.
2. Иррациональность - хорошо и точно подмечено. Знаки препинания систематически угождают в места полного отсутствия препинаний. Прямо говорить об этом обязательно нужно.
3. Выглядит как сильное преувеличение, но правильные учебники не спасли бы ситуацию: косноязычие настигает учащихся из телевизора, и он действует сильнее.
4. Тремя руками "за". Говорящим с детства по-русски нельзя преподавать русскую письменность по методологиям преподавания иностранных языков, т.е. злоупотреблять теоретизированием.

Comment: Alex_ander, в пункте 3, как мне кажется, речь идет не столько  о косноязычии, сколько о псевдонаучной деятельности наших специалистов. То, что раньше школьникам было понятно интуитивно (почему, например, вместо О мы говорим А), теперь получило теоретический базис - "науку", в которой смешаны все понятия о звуках и буквах, и эти ученые фантазии под видом русского языка изучают наши дети в школах. А вообще-то я не ожидала, что высказывания академика найдут поддержку: это во многом справедливая критика, но критика не созидающая, а разрушающая.

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы ссылочку, конечно. Или, как теперь принято говорить, *пруф*.

1. Без комментариев
2. Это, может быть, и верно, но только школьной-то программы практически не касается. А если дать по-настоящему трудный диктант, то ошибки будут делать почти все. Школьникам про это говорить не нужно хотя бы из педагогических соображений. Нашим школьникам только скажи...
3. Нет бы парочку подтверждений, а то что же так бездоказательно-то.
4. Чтобы именно грамотно писать — да. Но на уроках русского языка учат не только грамотно писать.

Comment: http://mytashkent.uz/2014/07/11/tochka-zreniya-shkolnyj-russkij/ По поводу п.2. Здесь речь не о том, что сложно не делать ошибки, а о том, что в самой системе письма академик не видит логики. Я же думаю, что наше письмо максимального логично для живой (не идеальной) системы, зависящей от многих факторов.

Comment: Вера, до представленной Вами ссылки, я думал, что это интервью с лингвистов в формате: вопрос-ответ. Оказалось, жирный текст принадлежит лингвисту. А кому принадлежит нежирный?

Comment: Прочитав дискуссию лингвистов, понял, что очень много преувеличено.